# How do I get Vim to source my .vimrc directly?

Tags: vim, homebrew, vi

I want to remove the color inverting from `<i></i>` elements. I added the line `highlight htmlItalic ctermbg=NONE` to my `.vimrc`, but when I load multiple files, say `file1.html` and `file2.html`, the `<i></i>` won't have inverted colors. However, if I type `:bn` `:bn` to go to the next buffer then back, the `<i></i>` will be inverted again. I must type `:source ~/.vimrc` to change it back. How do I stop this?

The result of `scriptnames` is:

```
1: ~/.vimrc
2: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
3: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
4: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
5: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
6: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/colors/zellner.vim
7: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/ftoff.vim
8: ~/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle.vim
9: ~/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle/config.vim
10: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
11: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
12: ~/.vim/plugin/RltvNmbr.vim
13: ~/.vim/autoload/RltvNmbr.vim
14: ~/.vim/plugin/RltvNmbrPlugin.vim
15: ~/.vim/bundle/auto-pairs/plugin/auto-pairs.vim
16: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdcommenter/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim
17: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
18: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
19: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/logiPat.vim
20: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/manpager.vim
21: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
22: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
23: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
24: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
25: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
26: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
27: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
28: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
29: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/scripts.vim
30: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/syntax/vim.vim
31: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/syntax/perl.vim
32: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/syntax/pod.vim
33: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/syntax/ruby.vim
34: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim
35: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/vim.vim
36: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/indent/vim.vim
37: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1864_1/share/vim/vim74/syntax/nosyntax.vim
```

I am on the latest version of vim via. Homebrew, and am NOT using gvim.
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly you want you to do? By default, lines in .vimrc is executed while entering any file through vim. Can you explain More, like what you want to happen?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I want the loaded vimrc to persist throughout buffer switches. Also, I want the vimrc to keep HTML italics from being color-highlighted.

Comment: In general, vimrc is persistent for all buffers opened through vim. I think you mean the wrong syntax coloring while opening a file. You can redraw the screen if you want. Can do this manually or automatically.

Comment: Any of the plugins you use might have caused this. Can you move the plugins under your home directory ( /home/aeon/.vim/) to some other directory and then try again and say.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! By the way, how do I have it automatically reload and redraw when I switch buffers?

Comment: You can  define an autocommand for that. `:au BufEnter *.* :redraw` put his in your vimrc and try again. It should work.